# How to add search params to Yii2 restfull api via ActiveController?

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

Im configured an API via default `ActiveController` extend. All works fine, I get all the data. But I need to receive the data of a specific user. Somehow like

```
Items::find()->andWhere(['user_id'=>Yii::app->user->id])
```

but in all actions in my API (`GET view`, `POST update`, etc). Also, I need to check - can this user change or get this row or not.

How I'd see it:

1. Model default work - I'll set a param in model, so model default work will use required search params;
2. I'm using a Search model instead of normal model;
3. Somehow to set access or modify the request via my `ItemController`, which extends `ActiveController` or somehow pass `params` to it.
4. Override default `ActiveController` crud actions and write my own.
5. Maybe, I should set rights and check from `checkAccess` via default `activecontroller` crud methods?

Dunno which way is right :(